# too greedy condition, or misused exception?

Tags: exception, coding-style

I have two alternative code fragments, with an intention to do (approximately) the same:

1. Closed-ended condition, with 3 cases of inputs resulting into just 2 cases of outputs:

   `this.showDropdowns ? parseInt(this.uploadForm.get('location').value, 10) : null;`
2. Open-ended conditioning, with 3 possible cases of inputs resulting into 3 recombined (table non-plain matching) cases of outputs:

   `try {parseInt(this.uploadForm.get('location').value, 10)} catch (ParseIntError e) {return null;}`

The first case is strict, allowing only the two resulting options explicitly prepared by the programmer: Either gives null (i), or the parsed value (ii), or the parsing falls (iii) back to the null.

See the [Closed/Open questions described on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Questionnaire_construction#Types_of_questions), to understand me what I mean.

The second code-fragment is not so greedy, does not swallow any possible exception, so the values are the two (three) expected by a programmer: The successfully parsed value (a), or there is still an allowed option for any unexpected result, as an explicitly caught Exception (also merging the null input/output case (b) with the parsing error exception (c), the non-null input, to be parsed, but unprocessable), but still yet allowing a fourth case of whatever completely unimaginable in the moment of the programming (d), still letting it to bubble up as an uncaught exception.

- The inputs could be just two, in general: null, or an Object.
- The outputs on the other hand could be more complicated:

  - the hardcoded null, after the IF;
  - the successfully parsed value;
  - or Exceptions:

    - Completely wrong Object-type for the particular parsing.
    - Parsable Object-type, but wrong values in it, in many ways...

So the questions:

- Is the first one too naive and too greedy, swallowing too much, or oppositely the aggregation/swallowing is the recommended way?
- Would the second be misusing of the mechanism of exceptions, or just the standard plain usage?

Are these known distinguished cases/options, how to resolve problems? These might be even so general, that there are some rules, philosophical how-to's or Good practices, to judge/recognize, when exactly to use the 1st, or the 2nd? So what are the rules, the recommendations? Thanks.